# PHP and PCI Compliance

Tags: php, pci-dss

I have a web server that needs to pass a PCI compiance scan by ControlScan.  Everything is good except for a scan they did of the PHP version.  I believe I have the latest version that CentOS provides.  Here's what they had to say:

> THREAT REFERENCE
>
> Summary:
>   vulnerable PHP version: 5.2.6
>
> Risk: High (3)
>   Port: 80/tcp
>   Protocol: tcp
>   Threat ID: web_prog_php_version
>
> <---REALLY LONG LIST OF PHP Vulnerabilities Trimmed--->
>
> Information From Target:
>   Service: http
>   Sent: GET /javascript/ HTTP/1.0
>   Host: 
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
>
> Received: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6

Here's my version of php:

> rpm -qa php
>   php-5.2.6-1.el5.art

From my understanding, it's backported so although it's not the latest version, it still has security patches applied.

I believe I have the latest version installed that CentOS allows (in fact I just did an update a couple weeks ago)  Here's the current output:

> yum update php
>   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
>   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>   * addons: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
>   * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
>   * extras: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
>   * updates: mirror.linux.duke.edu
>   addons                                                                                | 1.9 kB     00:00
>   base                                                                                  | 1.1 kB     00:00
>   extras                                                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00
>   updates                                                                               | 1.9 kB     00:00
>   Setting up Update Process
>   No Packages marked for Update

They asked for the changelog, so I ran:

> rpm -q --changelog php

but it lists no CVE's....  How can I determine if PHP actually contains these vulnerabilities?  I'm at the end of my rope with this...  It's frustrating because they're not actually testing vulnerabilities, they're just picking up a version number from the headers...   :/

Comment: The 'rpm -q --changelog php' should display any CVE's. Have you tried running it with 'rpm -q --changelog php | grep CVE'? Also, what version of CentOS are you running and have you updated using the default repo's at all?

Comment: @BlkStormy Dude. You're running ***PHP 5.2***. Sorry to be the one to break it to you but your environment is kinda screwed. It's virtually impossible to pass any kind of audit with something that old (and with that many known problems), and your upgrade/migration path takes you across a bunch of compatibility-breaking changes. I suggest you read through [the PHP Changelogs](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) and sit down with your boss to discuss the required work and/or possible compensating controls...

Answer (score 1):

It's even worse... You're using an old, and *third party* PHP package. Who knows if they've ever updated it? It's certainly not likely that they've backported security fixes.

You really should update PHP to the latest available 5.4 or 5.5 version; if you're using the upstream build or a third party build, that's the only way you can really be sure. Which means you should probably also update the OS to the latest available version.

Comment: I'm curious why you say it's old?  I literally just updated it from the repos via yum a couple weeks ago.  I realize it's not the latest version of PHP, but doesn't backporting come into play here with RH and CentOS?

Comment: You got PHP from a third party, not from Red Hat/CentOS. So there's only backporting if that third party is doing it (and you have no way to know). And PHP 5.2.6 was released on May 2008, and is missing thousands of bug fixes...

Comment: Not only was it released in May 2008, but it has been unsupported since January 2011. http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: So, how do I install the official one?  I was under the impression that yum automatically pulled that down (forgive my ignorance)

Comment: @BlkStormy see statement `Which means you should probably also update the OS to the latest available version.`

Comment: So in order to get the latest security updates for PHP via yum, I have to upgrade the OS?